# How to make sure python reads all files in folder?

Tags: python, excel, append

I've been saving this file in the folder I want python to read through - read through all files in the specific folder for all excel files ending with .xlsm. Everytime I run this, it skips over 1 file. The file it skips over, i've been opening and making sure the tab name is correct, then saving as a new file. Then, python reads it and adds it to the appended spreadsheet but skips over another file. Is there something incorrect with my code that limits the number of files it will read through?

They are all .xlsm files. There are 12 spreadsheets, all identical but different data points in each. All saved as similar naming structure but end with "phase #" going from 1-12. Is there any other code I can use to make sure it runs through all files? Goal is to read and append any sheet named 'data' rather than it being a macro file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('')
files = os.listdir(cwd)

df_total = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsm'):
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        sheets = excel_file.sheet_names
        for sheet in sheets:
            df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = 'Data', usecols = 'f', squeeze='true', skiprows=[2, 10, 11, 12])
            df_total = df_total.append(df)
            df_total = df_total.drop_duplicates()

df_total.T.to_excel(r' my file path \ file name.xlsx', sheet_name='All Data')
```

Comment: can you also share the file lists it tries to iterate over?

Comment: Probably not all of the files on your folder have a .xlsm extension.

Comment: Answered these questions, added to the original post

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would cause it to "skip over" a file. I don't understand why you think it is skipping anything. There's no way we could reproduce this without the data, I think.

Comment: I know it is skipping over a file because every time I run it, the first column on my new file has the file # referenced. It will go 1-3, skip 4, then go 5-12.

Comment: Well your new file also specifically drops duplicates so maybe there is that.

Comment: I deleted the line to drop duplicates. on my new sheet it repeats the same file 12 times. Is there another code I should be using to keep that from happening?

Comment: Your for loop `for sheet in sheets: ...` is strange: You don't use `sheet` in it, only `df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = 'Data', ...`. You are only reading the sheet with name `Data` -- why the looping? Are you sure all your files have a sheet named `Data`? Or did you actually intend to use `df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = sheet, ...`?